# PHPExcel_Writer_Exception with message "Could not close zip file php://output."

Tags: php, phpexcel, php-ziparchive

I'm using PHPExcel to export some data to user in an excel file. I would like the script to send the excel file to the user immediately after it's creation. Here is my test code:

```
try{

  /* Some test data */
  $data = array(
    array(1, 10   , 2             ,),
    array(3, 'qqq', 'some string' ,),
  );

  $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

  /* Fill the excel sheet with the data */
  $rowI = 0;
  foreach($data as $row){
    $colI = 0;
    foreach($row as $v){
      $colChar = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($colI++);
      $cellId = $colChar.($rowI+1);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($cellId, $v);
    }
    $rowI++;
  }

  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');

}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->__toString();
}
```

On my local server `(Windows 7 x64, Php 5.3.8, Apache 2.2.21)` I get a valid xlsx file. There are no errors. 
But there is problem on the live server `(Linux 2.6.32-5-amd64, PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze13, Apache 2.2.16)`. The script lets the browser to download the "export.xlsx" file with such content:

```
exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file php://output.' in /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/libs/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:348
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/classes/Report/Leads/Export.php(339): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('php://output')
#1 /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/application/pages/account/controllers/TestController.php(13): Report_Leads_Export->Test()
#2 /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/libs/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): Account_TestController->indexAction()
#3 /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/libs/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#4 /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/libs/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#5 /var/www/someuser/data/www/somedomain.com/index.php(511): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#6 {main}
```

PHP is NOT running in Safe Mode. The "open_basedir" option is empty (it's commented out).

I have found such code in the PHPExcel files:

```
if ($objZip->close() === false) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Writer_Exception("Could not close zip file $pFilename.");
}
```

So the reason of the problem is that `$objZip->close() === false` where `$objZip` is an instance of `ZipArchive` class.

What is the reason of the problem and how can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The most common cause of this error when saving to php://output is an open_basedir restriction that doesn't include a valid system's temp folder (e.g. `/tmp`), or permissions for the system's temp folder... suhosin can also affect this, even when the obvious permissions appear to be set correctly.

A possible workround is to write the file to the filesystem in a directory that you know you do have full privileges to write, and then use readfile() to stream that file to php://output before deleting the file

Comment: Suhosin is installed on the live server, but it's not on the local one. So suhosin may cause the problem. But I wouldn't like to see into it. I would like to solve the problem simply using a temp file, as you advice. Thank you!

Comment: In my case, I have a typo .. :<  so make sure you does not have any

Comment: Hey. Im goin into the same error. I tried to give /tmp and /var/tmp 777 and it does not work. How are you doin that?

Comment: Is there a solution not saving a temporary file to the filesystem?

Comment: I get that the file path is `./tml/export_123.xlsx` why the dot?

Comment: The first dot (`./`) ensures that the path is relative to the current working folder; the second dot (`export_123.xlsx`) is the separator between the filename and the file extension

Comment: Take care if you want to save to file, you must create a full parent path with `mkdir()` function, otherwise, you get `ZipArchive::close(): No error in ...`, because `Excel2007` doesn't create a path if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 28):

Thanks to Mark Baker. His answer has solved the problem. I have written a simple helper method using his approach.

```
static function SaveViaTempFile($objWriter){
    $filePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . "/" . rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".tmp";
    $objWriter->save($filePath);
    readfile($filePath);
    unlink($filePath);
}
```

And I have just replaced `$objWriter->save('php://output')` with `SaveViaTempFile($objWriter)`

Comment: Sounds great, but where do you have to replace this?

Answer (score 6):

Hi i tried the following:
in a server linux Centos 7.0 do not specified the route of directory tmp, input:

```
function SaveViaTempFile($objWriter){
    $filePath = '' . rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".tmp";
    $objWriter->save($filePath);
    readfile($filePath);
    unlink($filePath);
    exit;
}
```

and work !!

Comment: it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

For some people who may have this same ERROR message : it may very simply be because the filename you're trying to save to is actually already open in your Excel..
Was my case

Comment: this was in my case too, so it may happen to others, good to point it out.

Answer (score 2):

Excelent Friend Work for me in php 7.1.2 and work in PhpSpreadsheet, fix the same file.

```
PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Excel2007.php
```

the solution is in de function save in Excel2007.php

```
if (strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://output' || strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://stdout') {
    $pFilename = @tempnam(PHPExcel_Shared_File::sys_get_temp_dir(), 'phpxltmp');
```

Replace the second line with this:

```
$pFilename = dirname(__FILE__).'/'. rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".phpxltmp";
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve had the same error when I try run my php file, just change the in next line:

```
$objWriter->save("/dir1"."/".$file.".xlsx");
```

for this:

```
$objWriter->save(dirname(__FILE__)."/dir1"."/".$file.".xlsx");
```

add the the `dir` path and it worked!!!.

Answer (score 0):

And my answer is:
Filename had symbols such as ":", ",", '"'
Had to replace them to different ones. 
All worked

Answer (score 0):

This error happens also when trying to save a file into a folder that doesn't exist. Make sure the whole path exists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just tried to save file to folder, that wasn't exist. Created folder and problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It can also be caused by ownership issues of the directory where your PHPExcel (or its replacement - PhpSpreadsheet) is located.

Example for what can cause this to happen<sup>1</sup> - you upload a zip archive containing the PHPExcel / PhpSpreadsheet library, via FTP/SFTP to your website / webapp. Then, you use `unzip phpexcelarchive.zip -d ./example.com` via the terminal to extract the archive with your files.

Depending on how you were logged in to the console / terminal (root, or some other kind of user with different privileges, belonging to a specific group, etc) when decompressing / unzipping the archive, that particular user will be set as the owner of the files and directories created by unzipping the archive.

This *could* cause problems later on, as it *might* limit what you can do with PHPExcel / PhpSpreadsheet - the titular error being one thing that could happen.

The solution would be to unzip the archive programmatically (with a PHP script, and the use of `echo exec('unzip phpexcelarchive.zip -d ./example.com')`), or via your control panel's (cPanel, Plesk, something else), and its built-in extractor within the File Manager.

This will make your Apache (or the equivalent) user the owner of the unpacked directories and files.

---

<sup>1</sup> You should really have a good reason for installing / setting up PHPExcel / PhpSpreadsheet like this. The preferable way of installing it is via composer.

Answer (score -1):

The following works for the Excel2007 format. It would need to be adapted for different formats.

---

Open this file:

```
\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007.php
```

Look near Line 196 for:

```
if (strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://output' || strtolower($pFilename) == 'php://stdout') {
    $pFilename = @tempnam(PHPExcel_Shared_File::sys_get_temp_dir(), 'phpxltmp');
```

Replace the second line with this:

```
    $pFilename = dirname(\__FILE__).'/'. rand(0, getrandmax()) . rand(0, getrandmax()) . ".phpxltmp";
```

Then you can use the export-function as described in the developer guide.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I modify the permissions of the target folder to rwxrwxrwx (0777) and now works!

Comment: You should never configure your server directories to be readable and writable by the entire world.

Answer (score -2):

It's caused by dir permission. Try to enter the final folder, then `chmod -R 777 [folder_name]`. It should work :)

Comment: This will open up the server to anyone, do not do this

Answer (score -3):

set chmod 777 -R public/results

Comment: This will open up the server to anyone, dont do this.