# How to install PhpPresentation

Tags: php, phppresentation

I've manually installed PhpPresentation from GitHub on Windows server 2008 (IIS 7)
But when I run example from this installation - it does not work and show different errors.
I managed to fix few errors. But right now it show error that I can not find on the Internet:

PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\ComparableInterface not found in ......\Color.php

How can I figure out what is wrong with installation and fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you registered the autoloader?

Comment: require_once 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\classes\phpoffice\PHPPresentation\Autoloader.php'; 
#\phpoffice\PHPPresentation\Autoloader::register(); # for manual installation
Autoloader::register(); # for manual installation

Comment: I try to use code above to register - but it show error  Class "Autoloader" not found

Comment: require_once 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\classes\phpoffice\PHPPresentation\Autoloader.php';  
Autoloader::register();

Comment: Also this file does exist and has class Autoloader with function register()

Comment: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\classes\phpoffice\PHPPresentation\Autoloader.php

Comment: Your paths seem wrong, they are different on https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation. I'd suggest you to go with recommended composer installation, it should fix all issues.

Comment: php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
 php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
 php composer-setup.php
 php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Comment: I am trying to install composer with code above but it gives me error: Installer corrupt :-(

Comment: This was fixed when I use new version of composer installation :-)

Comment: Now try to run new 1st sample and it is working fine when run from command line but when I access it from browser - it show error below and output file is not generated. I added all permissions to folder 'results'...

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\samples/Sample_01_Simple.pptx.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CLASS_PhpPresentation\vendor\phpoffice\common\src\Common\Adapter\Zip\ZipArchiveAdapter.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CLASS_PhpPresentation\vendor\phpoffice\phppresentation\src\PhpPresentation\Writer\PowerPoint2007.php(131): PhpOffice\Common\Adapter\Zip\ZipArchiveAdapter->close()
#1 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\samples\Sample_Header.php(102): PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Writer\PowerPoint2007->save('C:\\inetpub\\wwwr...')

Comment: #2 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\samples\Sample_01_Simple.php(58): write(Object(PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\PhpPresentation), 'Sample_01_Simpl...', Array)
#3 {main}
  thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CLASS_PhpPresentation\vendor\phpoffice\common\src\Common\Adapter\Zip\ZipArchiveAdapter.php on line 36

Comment: Cool, so you have a different error now. If you searched for solutions you probably saw this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21436949/phpexcel-writer-exception-with-message-could-not-close-zip-file-php-output.
Or you'd better ask via "Issues" tab in PhpPresentation github repository instead.

Comment: Thanks!!! Your comments are really helping  :-) Now it generate pptx file with image from sample1 and it can be opened in PowerPoint

Comment: But there is one more problem - when this file is opened by PowerPoint it show some warning: PowerPoint found unreadable content in sample1.pptx. Do you want to recover the contents? When I click YES - file is shown... Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: It is definitely better to ask this in the repository for that package, because it sounds like their specific issue. Happy New Year btw! :)

Comment: Yes, it looks  like it generate pptx for older version of PowerPoint and it can not be handled by new versions of PowerPoint... Happy New Year for you too :-)

Answer (score 0):

as described on [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phppresentation), PhpPresentation depends on the PhpOffice\Common package :

https://github.com/PHPOffice/Common

So you download it and install it, and use it as :

```
include 'PhpOffice\PHPPresentation\Autoloader.php'; 
include 'PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader.php'; 
\PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();
\PhpOffice\PHPPresentation\Autoloader::register();
```

Comment: That did not help - it generate same pptx file with same warning