# Opening excel received as response from the rest service

Tags: rest, web-services, xlsx

I am using the following code at server side

```
 return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM*)
                  .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=somename.xlsx" )
                  .build();
```

I want to directly open the file in some application (preferably ms-excel) I have tried using inline instead of attachment and I also tried using

```
@Produces("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
```

All I am able to do is download and open, I want it to open directly rather than downloading.

Comment: */ is typed out as mistake in the first line of code, sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPExcel: Automatically download and open an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189296/phpexcel-automatically-download-and-open-an-excel-file)