# jasperreports large excel file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I have some reports which I export them using *JasperReports* library. It is all fine except excel files (xls). For example when I try to export an exact report with 751 rows as an excel file, there are no problems and the excel file will be downloaded correctly, but when it exceeds 800 rows, it will show some unrelated characters. The row size mentioned above is just for this report and for other reports the limit is on different numbers. This problem does not exist before I upgrade the libraries from version 2.3 to 6.1.0 and now I tried 6.2.2.

This is how I create my excel file:

```
    JasperPrint jasperPrint;
    try {
        jasperPrint = getReportPrint(request, baseForm, "excel");
    } catch (ReportNoDataException e) {
        return handleNoData(mapping, request, e);
    }

    try {
        JRXlsExporter jrXlsExporter = new JRXlsExporter();
        try {
            jrXlsExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            jrXlsExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));

            SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setIgnoreCellBorder(true);
            configuration.setWrapText(true);
            configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
            configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
            configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
            configuration.setAutoFitPageHeight(true);
            configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
            configuration.setSheetDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);

            jrXlsExporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
            jrXlsExporter.exportReport();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException occured" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JRException e) {
            log.error("JRException occured while exporting for xls format", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    String filename="report";
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\""+filename+".xls\"");
    putSearchForm(request, baseForm);
    return null;
```

here is the report code:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="mtdTankhahEdaratMojoodiExcelReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="60" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" scriptletClass="report.webapp.tlmReportScriptlet" uuid="4354b1d9-63b2-4236-b190-ac5b2fb0f464">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="no" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[no]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="baseDate" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[baseDate]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="pardakht" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pardakht]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="daryaft" class="java.lang.Double">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[daryaft]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="zinaf" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[zinaf]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="sanadType" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sanadType]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<variable name="mande" class="java.lang.Double">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{pardakht}==null || $F{daryaft}==null) ? new Double(0) :
(new Double(($F{daryaft}.doubleValue()-$F{pardakht}.doubleValue())+
$V{mande}.doubleValue()))]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double("0")]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
<title>
    <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-4" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" uuid="36cd81f4-073b-4023-b5b8-716d43a4d377">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ردیف]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-8" x="275" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="0827df09-4353-424e-94fa-dd8cc7d5c6ac">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[نوع سند]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-9" x="190" y="0" width="85" height="30" uuid="13490ca9-0ba0-4315-b5a0-745ce020f9e1">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[تاریخ سند]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-12" x="110" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="544625a2-83d3-405d-a117-c0fa6820813a">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[شماره سند]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-14" x="355" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="fc76869a-b6b1-4223-8ab3-26a870a23e08">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[دریافت]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-14" x="515" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="f53ebc1b-eaaa-487b-bd23-ee62a1534caa"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[مانده]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-14" x="435" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="aa3bda32-9b4c-4e53-927a-f6750256fb51"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[پرداخت]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement key="staticText-12" x="30" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="b8c6b055-1b5e-4923-954b-a4eed5bab543">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[ذینفع]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-1" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="263cfc8f-7812-4797-843c-42fe00045f98">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-5" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="355" y="0" width="80" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="baaa6584-8b9d-4523-a698-a68d065b8892"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{daryaft} == null)? new Double("0"): $F{daryaft}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-6" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="190" y="0" width="85" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="073a34ff-2e81-4265-a580-beb8fb293ae0"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{baseDate} == null)? "---" : $F{baseDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-9" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="110" y="0" width="80" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="e1c072ca-5d06-453c-a739-c797507a92b0"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{no} == null)? "---" : $F{no}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-11" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="435" y="0" width="80" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a5778bf8-71da-4c84-82b8-219f27f04065"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{pardakht} == null)? new Double("0"): $F{pardakht}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-11" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="515" y="0" width="80" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="a762bdfa-4d3f-4975-b70d-d25875d15af8"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($V{mande} == null)? new Double("0"): $V{mande}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-5" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="275" y="0" width="80" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="d8c12462-e172-47eb-a301-905e356465b2"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{sanadType} == null)? "---": $F{sanadType}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement key="textField-9" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="30" y="0" width="80" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="7eae6f3a-173e-479d-90d7-38b6c5a5b99f"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="bnazanin" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{zinaf} == null)? "---" : $F{zinaf}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

and here is the screenshot from the report:
[image: report result]

Is there any idea how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you are looking at is the Excel output. This is what an Excel file looks like if you open it in a text editor (I took a random XLS file and opened it in Notepad++):

[image]

This means, that your response is not providing the content as a Excel file but as a direct download, which is shown directly in the Browser.

Try adding additional parameters to your response ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856550/5191221) and set to fit Java) to be more explicit:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
response.setHeader("Expires: 0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control: private");
```

**EDIT**

If this happens to bigger files, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6520353/5191221) which describes the same problem. In general it says, you should send response headers as early as possible and then afterwards generate the report file.

Put short: You should first write all contents to the header first (I suspect you do have more on `response` higher up) and then try to generate the file. So the browser gets a result, sees that an application file is coming and will provide a download. Otherwise, as far as I understand it, the `response` header is set after the file is generated - which could be too long for the browser to wait for the `Content-Type`.

Comment: I tried every contentType and headers which found in the Internet, and nothing work for me. The code works for small excel files and it creates a downloadable file, but for larger files it changes and show this web page. I think there is no limit for file size because I can export large pdf files and this happens just for excel files. Is there any other settings which I can change?

Comment: Added a more specific answer regarding your follow-up question.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer (or another one) has helped you out, consider accepting it as an answer (see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) so that others can see it as well.