# Yii2 download model as an excel file

Tags: php, rest, yii2, phpexcel

I'm working on a Yii2 rest Api that's connected to AngularJS front end.

I'm trying to build an `actionDownloadAsExcel` method that can help me download a specific model. What would be a good way to do this?

I installed "phpOffice\phpExcel" but I don't really know how to use it for my purpose.

Comment: I suggest you read **[How to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the data you want to save to the excel, print that using an html table and setting a proper excel header before the view is rendered:

```
header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=abc.xls");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
```

Source:
[PHP Excel Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856518/php-excel-header)